# How to change CMFCToolBar runtime

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, cmfctoolbar

I need under certain conditions to switch toolbars in my SDI application using the same CMFCToolBar object, which is the member of CMainFrame. I'm trying to do it like this:

```
void CMainFrame::ChangeTlbr(const int tlbIdx)
{
    m_wndToolBar.ResetImages();
    switch (tlbIdx)
    {
        case 0 :

            m_wndToolBar.LoadToolBar(IDR_TLBR1);

            break;
        case 1:

            m_wndToolBar.LoadToolBar(IDR_TLBR2);

            break;
    }

    m_wndToolBar.Invalidate();
    m_wndToolBar.UpdateWindow();
}
```

But bitmap of the next toolbar is not loaded.

What am i doing wrong in this case, and if there is better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following function shows how to replace the current toolbar by another one, defined as **IDR_MAINFRAME1**:

```cpp
void CMainFrame::OnChangeToolbar()
{    
    m_wndToolBar.ResetAllImages();
    m_wndToolBar.LoadToolBar(IDR_MAINFRAME1);
    m_wndToolBar.LoadBitmap(IDR_MAINFRAME1);
    m_wndToolBar.AdjustSizeImmediate();        
}
```

Comment: Thanx alot. Also I had to add `wndToolBar.ShowPane(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE);` at the and, otherwise the part of previous toolbar remained seen.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't passing the required resource IDs of the bitmaps to be loaded in your call to [CMFCToolBar::LoadToolBar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983090.aspx):

> *uiColdResID*
>   The resource ID of the bitmap that refers to the cold toolbar images.
>
> *uiMenuResID*
>   The resource ID of the bitmap that refers to the regular menu images.
>
> *uiDisabledResID*
>   The resource ID of the bitmap that refers to the disabled toolbar images.
>
> *uiMenuDisabledResID*
>   The resource ID of the bitmap that refers to the disabled menu images.
>
> *uiHotResID*
>   The resource ID of the bitmap that refers to the hot toolbar images.

At the very least you need to specify *uiHotResID*. If you do not want (or have) images for the other parameters, you can call [CMFCToolBar::LoadBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983369.aspx) instead. A final call to [CMFCToolBar::AdjustLayout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb984532.aspx) recalculates the controls size and position.